# Is an instance of a concrete subclass an instance of the abstract class?

Tags: python, abstract-class, instantiation

By definition, we cannot *instantiate* an abstract class:

```py
>>> import abc
>>> class A(abc.ABC):
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def f(self): raise NotImplementedError
... 
>>> A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class A with abstract method f
```

So isn’t it a contradiction that an instance of a concrete subclass is an *instance of* the abstract class?

```py
>>> class B(A):
...     def f(self): return 'foo'
... 
>>> isinstance(B(), A)
True
```

Comment: I think it is an instance because it does follow the blueprint of the abstract class i.e. can be considered of the abstract type class (thus enabling polymorphism). this is similar to interfaces in java for example. Where you cannot make an interface instance but can create object from classes that implement it thus making possible to use as if they were of the interface type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between an object *being* an instance of a class and the act of *instantiating* a class. Inheritance means that if `B` is a subclass of `A`, then `isinstance(B(), A)` is true, even though `B`, not `A`, is the class being instantiated.

If you could never concretize an abstract class, there would be no point in defining the abstract class in the first place. The purpose of an abstract class is to provide an incomplete template for other classes; you can't simply use the abstract class as-is without doing making some additional definitions.

Put another way, given `b = B()`, `b` is an *instance* of `A` and `B`, but only `B` is the *type* of `b`. Is-type-of and is-instance-of are two different relations.

Comment: I agree, my confusion came from the fact that abstract classes cannot be instantiated but can have instances. I realized that there is actually no contradiction: *cannot be instantiated* means *cannot create instances*, not *instances cannot be created*. Abstract class instances can still be created by a concrete subclass.